# XML to Java and vice versa using xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Below is my Schema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/address" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.org/address" schemaLocation="www.example.org_address.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="dependant" type="dependant"/>
  <xs:element name="employee" type="employee"/>

  <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="dependantVO" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="dependant" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="address" type="ns1:address" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="dob" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="joiningBonus" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="permanent" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="role" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="dependant">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="relation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Below is my address.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/address" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="addressLine1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="addressLine2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now if i marshal the object "Employee" below is the generated employee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee id="12">
    <dependantVO>
        <dependant>
            <name>Vin Diesel</name>
            <relation>Friend</relation>
        </dependant>
        <dependant>
            <name>Black Ryan</name>
            <relation>GF</relation>
        </dependant>
    </dependantVO>
    <address>
        <addressLine1>My Company</addressLine1>
        <addressLine2>bangalore east</addressLine2>
        <city>Bangalore</city>
        <zip>560549</zip>
    </address>
    <dob>2015-07-28T10:04:34.599+05:30</dob>
    <joiningBonus>10234.35467000000062398612499237060546875</joiningBonus>
    <name>Paul Walker</name>
    <permanent>true</permanent>
    <role>SE</role>
</employee>
```

I have a problem of ordering the xml tags. Eg: Suppose i want addressline1 to be generated inside "employee" tag and outside "address" tag, also dependant name to be generated inside "employee" tag and outside "dependantVO" and "dependant" tag. Below is the xml that should be generated after the schema change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <employee id="12">
    <addressLine1>My Company</addressLine1>
    <city>Bangalore</city>
        <dependantVO>
            <dependant>
                <name>Vin Diesel</name>
                <relation>Friend</relation>
            </dependant>
            <dependant>
                <name>Black Ryan</name>
                <relation>GF</relation>
            </dependant>
        </dependantVO>
        <address>
            <addressLine2>bangalore east</addressLine2>
            <zip>560549</zip>
        </address>
        <dob>2015-07-28T10:04:34.599+05:30</dob>
        <joiningBonus>10234.35467000000062398612499237060546875</joiningBonus>
        <name>Paul Walker</name>
        <permanent>true</permanent>
        <role>SE</role>
    </employee>
```

Note the addressLine1 tag and city tag is out of address tag and created inside employee tag. This is required because some of the common information are to be accessed easy from the generated xml. If someone tried this case or already done it, please help me out...

Comment: I don't quite get it... You want to produce an XML file that is not valid for the Schema you are using? Or do you want to modify them Schema?

Comment: So, the easiest way would be to modify the XSD...

Comment: Yes i tried putting the tag outside in schema its not working. Can someone give me an example ??

Comment: I guess you are using JAXB. So you have to modify the XSD, moving the `<xs:element name="addressLine1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>` somehwere and then you have to recreate your classes, probably via the xjc tool. You could also modify the files by hand, but that would probably be quite error-prone for you.

Comment: Try intellijIdea, it has a tool to create XSD Schema from an XML file. So you produce your desired XML output and then generate the schema out of it. After that you can do as you did before.

Comment: No Im comfortable with "schema file from java class" in eclipse. It gives me proper schema file. Im worried about changing xml hierarchy keeping java object classes constant.